# Upgrade from 9.10 to 11.04

Tags: upgrade, versions

I have an installation in my machine (my version is 9.10 Karmic) and I got a warning to Upgrade to a version 10.04, to me it is okay, and I would like to upgrade to the 10.04, but here is my question.

If I do, what will happen to my system of files? All my files? My programs, my apache configuration? All my servers.. Does everything reset to default? Will I lost all my data? Because if YES, will lost everything, why such a warning appears to me?

Then the best solution is, format everything and install a brand new ubuntu version 11.

Otherwise I still using 9.10 Karmic version,and just update normally as I'm required..

What is the best to do on this situation?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't lose anything if you upgrade. Make a backup beforehand, though!
See the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes) on how to upgrade. You're going to have to do it step-by-step (9.10->10.04...).

Comment: The only problem that I forsee is that during the upgrade something dies.  Now realistically, from 9.10 -> 10.04, such death is rare.  However, if you do the other step-by-step upgrading (10.04 -> 10.10, 10.10 -> whatever), the risk that something dies increases, and that risk gets higher with each upgrade-upon-upgrade.

Comment: Thanks guys, anyway I ll upgrade to 10.04. and after tell you how it was..

Comment: @Fernando: You might just be better off backing up your data and then installing fresh, it might avoid you having to deal with broken packages during the upgrade-upon-upgrade process.  :/

Comment: Does it mean, format the whole disc and install a fresh new brand copy of ubuntu 11 ??? If yes, it is a problem because I have to much data on my pc, and backing up everything now is a kind of painful task..  but thanks @EvilPhoenix with your advice.

Comment: And what about the apache, mysql, php and all other stuffs that do not come by default with ubuntu ? Does everything will be lost??

Comment: The upgrade shouldn't remove those programs unless something really bad (=bug) happens. The upgrader will tell you what programs it's going to install/update and delete. Your settings will be untouched, if the upgrader needs to update a config file, it'll ask for your permission first.

Comment: Right.  The upgrade won't harm your apache mysql or php stuff, but it will update them after the upgrade.

Comment: Upgrade will keep your stuff, but a clean install won't.   I want to add here that I have two machines which have been upgraded over the years starting at around 8.10 until now, and never had problems. YMMV of course.